# python2.7: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, proxy, urllib

I'm trying to install ROS from source.

When I execute the command of installation, I get such an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 126, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 73, in main
    urllib.urlretrieve('https://github.com/assimp/assimp/archive/v3.1.1.zip', dest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1263, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:661)
/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/mk/download_unpack_build.mk:37: recipe for target 'build/assimp-3.1.1/unpacked' failed
make[3]: *** [build/assimp-3.1.1/unpacked] Error 1
```

I don't know how to solve this issue. Maybe it's because I worked behind a proxy? If so, how to make `urllib.urlretrieve` work behind the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add proxy settings to your global environment to see if it fixes the problem.

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Then add these two lines

```
http_proxy=http://your_proxy.com:443
https_proxy=https://your_proxy.com:443
```